# How to convert a hexa string to an binary byte array?

Tags: java, binary, hex, byte

I want to transform a hexa string into a binary byte array as written in the title

### THE MAIN CODE :

```
String r16 = "15d626926b7567f7";

byte[] binary64 = hexToBinary64Bits(r16);
System.out.println("r16 : " + r16);

for (int i = 0; i < binary64.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(binary64[i] + ", ");
}
```

---

```
   public static byte[] hexToBinary64Bits(String hex) {

    return ((String.format("%64s", 

        Long.toBinaryString(Long.parseLong(hex,16))).

        replace(" ", "0")).getBytes());

}
```

---

**THE RESULT**

```
r16 : 15d626926b7567f7

48, 48, 48, 49, 48, 49, 48, 49, 49, 49, 48, 49, 48, 49, 49, 48, 48, 48, 49, 48, 48, 49, 49, 48, 49, 48, 48, 49, 48, 48, 49, 48, 48, 49, 49, 48, 49, 48, 49, 49, 48, 49, 49, 49, 48, 49, 48, 49, 48, 49, 49, 48, 48, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 48, 49, 49, 49,
```

I don't want to hava 48, 48, 48, 49 but 0, 0, 0, 1 and I must be the most efficient :)

Thanks a lot !

Comment: 48 is the int value of  the char '0'.  To show char instead of int, cast the bytes to char when printing.

Comment: char ch = (char) binary64[i];
      System.out.print(ch + ", ");

Comment: Thank you :) But if i need to store these 1 and 0 , do i have to create a new array or there is a java function that make the job ? Because it need to be really performing  (Sorry for my bad english ^^